# Correct way of passing data back to previous page with Expo Router?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation, expo-router

I have two pages in my app currently, Page1 and Page2. On Page1, I do the following to open Page2 using Expo Router:

```
<Link href="/page2" asChild>
  <TouchableOpacity>
    <Text>Go to Page 2</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</Link>
```

On Page2, I have a form with two fields and a Submit button. When the user taps the Submit button, it sends the data to my backend and backend returns an object. At this point, I need to close Page2 pass that object back to Page1, but I'm not sure how to do this with Expo Router.

The submit function on Page2:

```
const submit = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await postRequest('form/insert', { name: name, amount: amount });
    const json = response.data;

    console.log(response);

    // How do I send the json data back to Page1?
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Thank you

Answer (score -3):

page 1:

`const [value, updateValue] = useState(1)`

`navigate('page2', { updateValue : updateValue }`

page 2:

```
 pop()
 updateValue(2)
```